# Option Arrow keys for moving cursor by word for file paths in terminal (macOS Catalina) in zsh

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, macos

I've recently updated my terminal shell to zsh on Mac OS Catalina and have found one difference from before, in which I'd prefer the previous behavior. When working in Terminal, using option arrows would move my cursor forward or backwards by one word each time. For file paths, it would move it by one directory at a time in my file path. With my update, I now see that when using this key combination with file paths in my command, instead of going directory by directory, it treats the entire file path as a single word. As I often change just parts of my file path for some repeated commands, I would like to know if anyone else had experienced this or found a workaround.

Comment: You'll find many  similar questions here if [you search for `select-word-style`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=select-word-style) (`select-word-style`, specifically `select-word-style bash` here, being one of the possible answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following to your `.zshrc` file:

```bash
WORDCHARS=''
```

This will make only alphanumeric characters count as words.

More info:

- https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-WORDCHARS
- https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-forward_002dword

---

Alternatively, for even more intuitive, customizable word movement, try my [Zsh Edit plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-edit).

Comment: Thanks!  Works great!

Comment: @BTBts Then please click the button to "Accept" my answer. :)

Comment: Done, do you also know if I can add underscore (_) as an accepted character to skip with alphanumeric characters in WORDCHARS?

Comment: Yeah, of course. Just change it to `WORDCHARS='_'`. You can put any characters you like in there. I personally use `'*?\'`.